# relation is stated yet gives Integrity constraint violation where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, yii

okay how is this ambiguous? I have the relationship table in there. I also have tried adding an alias. Both ways gave me ambiguous.

```
    public function defaultScope()
    {
        $t = $this->getTableAlias(false,false);
        if ($t=='t'){
            $sid = Yii::app()->user->store();
            return array(
                    'with'=>array('product'),
                    'condition'=>'product.store_id=:store_id' ,
                    'params' => array(':store_id' => $sid)
            );
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }

    public function defaultScope()
        {
            $sid = Yii::app()->user->store();
            return array(
                    'with'=>array('product'),
                    'condition'=>'product.store_id=:store_id' ,
                    'params' => array(':store_id' => $sid)
            );
        }
```

Comment: why you have two function name as duplicate ?

Comment: what? that was just saying the two ways i tried.

Comment: it will be good to add here complete exception messages. This way is hard to say what is exactly duplicate